# What is wrong with this locking scheme

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3

```
for (NSString * district in allLinedStrings) {
    PO1(district);
    [self.mainLock lock];
    CLGeocoder * geocode= [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
    [geocode geocodeAddressString:district completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error )
     {
         for (CLPlacemark * thePlace in placemarks)
         {
             [self handlePlacemark:thePlace];

         }
         [self.mainLock unlock];
     }];
}
```

I want to run geocodeAddressString synchronously and I do this. Somehow I got error of deadlock. But what's wrong?

Comment: *I want to run geocodeAddressString synchronously and I do this* -- the APIs are asynchronous for a reason. you should follow that lead, and reflow your program. e.g. hold on to the array of `allLinedStrings`, process, process next when completion is called…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using NSLock: Calling the lock method twice on the same thread will lock up your thread permanently.

```
for (NSString * district in allLinedStrings) {
    PO1(district);
    [self.mainLock lock];
    CLGeocoder * geocode= [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
    [geocode geocodeAddressString:district completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error )
     {
         for (CLPlacemark * thePlace in placemarks)
         {
             [self handlePlacemark:thePlace];

         }

     }];
[self.mainLock unlock];
}
```

Comment: well, we don't know if `self.mainLock` is a recursive lock or not…

Comment: Care to address that? I thought it should just wait till unlocking.